# Reading IPA sentence

Tags: english, ipa

I'm trying to read the following sentence. It should be some film or play (English).

[image]

I'd be glad if you could help me with translating

Comment: I doubt that this transcription is correct, phonemically or phonetically.

Comment: Why do you think so? It was taken from the book "Looking at Languages: A Workbook in Elementary Linguistics"

Comment: I was able (If not mistaken) to read it as "* * for other programs"

Comment: Dialects with flapping don't have [r]; there is no schwa-r sequence. Aspiration should be omitted if this is a phonemic transcription; ʌ vs. ə is allophonic. It's an unsystematic mixed bag of IPA letters.

Comment: Why is it considered off-topic? it has an IPA tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that this should be a particular film or play? The last three words are clearly "for other programs" (in American English the "o" in "for" is often pronounced with a schwa).

Looking at the other two words, I would say this reads **Call theater for other programs**. Note that the middle symbol in the second word, though it looks like an "r", is in fact an alveolar flap - the sound an English speaker often makes when pronouncing a /t/ or /d/ in the middle of a word.

Comment: Oh I get this. It was the last given title and it is suggesting the reader (as a joke) to call theater for other programs! Thanks a lot!